# How to combine null values and varchar values in SQL?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am working with a particularly annoying dataset. I have just managed to get the data to align with what is expected but now I am having trouble with merging/combining some rows so that I have a neater table. To help you understand this is what I am getting:

| order_id | aso_flag | dpo_flag | tcv | ops | penalty_charge |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4540 | N | Y | 1.7 | 0 | 0 |
| 4540 |  |  |  | 1.4 | 0 |

And this is what I desire:

| order_id | aso_flag | dpo_flag | tcv | ops | penalty_charge |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4540 | N | Y | 1.7 | 1.4 | 0 |

and this is the bottom of my current query:

```
SELECT  
order_id
,NULL AS aso_flag
,dpo_flag
,tcv
,0 AS ops
,0 AS penalty_charge

FROM CO

UNION ALL

SELECT 
order_id
,aso_flag
,null AS dpo_flag
,0 AS tcv
,ops
,penalty_charge

FROM OPS
```

The initial tables used don't mirror each other exactly (missing order_ids) and a full join on them seems to be very very slow. Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: looks like you need to add a constraint on order_id so you can JOIN efficiently.

Comment: use `group by` then `max`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derived Table from your `Union` then `group by` and `max`

```
SELECT
  order_id,
  MAX(aso_flag) aso_flag,
  MAX(dpo_flag) dpo_flag,
  MAX(tcv) tcv,
  MAX(ops) ops,
  MAX(penalty_charge) penalty_charge
FROM (SELECT
  order_id,
  NULL AS aso_flag,
  dpo_flag,
  tcv,
  0 AS ops,
  0 AS penalty_charge

FROM CO

UNION ALL

SELECT
  order_id,
  aso_flag,
  NULL AS dpo_flag,
  0 AS tcv,
  ops,
  penalty_charge

FROM OPS) x
GROUP BY order_id
```